# calculate the space time complexity of dart and flutter programs

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-test

do we have a dart lib readily available to calculate the space-time complexity of dart programs?

I am building an automated CI CD pipeline, and to do code quality control we need to implemented complexity checks on the code.

Comment: Is this not equivalent to solving [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)?

Comment: Mmm I mainly need a library which can analyze and produce complexity metrics of my codebase. There are such framework and library for other programming languages. I hope there is something for dart too